# Adding multiple dictionaries to a key in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to add multiple dictionaries to a key.
e.g.

```
value = { column1 : {entry1 : val1}
                    {entry2 : val2}

          column2 : {entry3 : val3}
                    {entry4 : val4}
}
```

What exactly I am trying to do with this code is:
There is a file.txt which has columns and valid entries for that header. I am trying to make a dictionary with columns as key and for each column another dictionary for each valid entry.
So I am parsing the text file line by line to find the pattern for column and entries and storing it in a variable, check if the column(which is a key) already exists in the dictionary, if exists then add another dictionary to the column, if not create a new entry. I Hope this makes sense.

Sample contents of file.txt

```
blah blah Column1 blah blah
    entry1 val1
    entry2 val2
blah blah Column2 blah blah
    entry3 val3
    entry4 val4
```

My code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import os, re, string, gzip, fnmatch, io
from array import *

header = re.compile(...) #some regex
valid_entries = re.compile(---) #some regex

matches=[]
entries=[]
value = {'MONTH OF INTERVIEW' : {'01': 'MIN VALUE'}}
counter = 0
name = ''

f =open(r'C:/file.txt')

def exists(data, name):
    for key in data.keys():
        if key == name :
            print "existing key : " + name
            return True
        else :
            return False
for line in f:

    col = ''
    ent = ''
    line = re.sub(ur'\u2013', '-', line)
    line = re.sub(ur'\u2026', '_', line)
    m = header.match(line)
    v = valid_entries.match(line)

    if m:
        name= ''
        matches.append(m.groups())
        _,_, name,_,_= m.groups()
        #print "name : " + name

    if v:
        entries.append(v.groups())
        ent,col= v.groups()
        #print v.groups()
        #print "col :" + col
        #print "ent :" + ent

    if (name is not None) and (ent is not None) and (col is not None):
        print value
        if exists(value, name):
            print 'inside existing loop'
            value[name].update({ent:col})
        else:
            value.update({name:{ent:col}})

print value
```

### problem with this code is , it is replacing the values of the sub dictionary and also it is not adding all the values to the dictionary.

I am new to python, so this could be a naive approach to handle this kind of situation. If you think there is a better way of getting what I want, I would really appreciate if you tell me.

Comment: Your data suggests you are trying to map numbers to strings; so for the `Gender` column, you can create *one* dictionary with `{1: 'Female', 2: 'Male'}`, not a list of dictionaries.

Comment: ohk So, there will be dictionary with all the column names and 1 dictionary for valid entries for each keys. This makes sense. I will try to implement this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries have only **one** value per key. The trick is to make that value a container too, like a list:

```
value = {
    'column1': [{entry1 : val1}, {entry2 : val2}]
    'column2': [{entry3 : val3}, {entry4 : val4}]
}
```

Use `dict.setdefault()` to insert a list value when there is no value yet:

```
if name is not None and ent is not None and col is not None:
    value.setdefault(name, []).append({ent: col})
```

You could just make the values *one* dictionary with multiple `(ent, col)` key-value pairs here:

```
if name is not None and ent is not None and col is not None:
    value.setdefault(name, {})[ent] = col
```

Your `exists()` function was overcomplicating a task dictionaries excel at; testing for a key is done using `in` instead:

```
if name in value:
```

would have sufficed.

Comment: My next step of this project is:
There is csv file with columns as headers and entry as the rows.
So I have to check the column of the csv, match it with the dictionary key and replace the entry with the values. Do you think it is achievable by making it a container?? Pardon my ignorance please. I am new to this.

Comment: I'm not certain why you need a list of dictionaries here in the first place. Are the keys not unique?

Comment: But anything you can put *into* a list, you can get out again too.

Comment: Keys are unique but there can be multiple valid entries for a particular column.
e.g in my data.csv file there is column:
Gender, it has values 1 or 2.
In file.txt it the valid entries of the gender is 1:Female, 2:Male,
so I want to replace 1 with female and 2 with male in my data.csv file.

Comment: There are 400 columns in data.csv, so I cannot do it manually. I have to write a code for that. If you could suggest me a better way of doing this, I would really appreciate

Comment: I'm having some trouble following what you are trying to do, and comments are not really the place to do follow-up questions. Perhaps you need to post a *new* question in which you explain what you are trying to do; you'll have more room and time.

Comment: let me just extend my question.

Comment: @user3780390: no, I already answered *this* question. Please don't [change your question after having received an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). Questions are meant to be helpful not just for you but other, future visitors as well.

Comment: oh ok. I will ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the keys as a list of dictionaries, so you can `extend` or `append`

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d[1] = [{'a': 1}]
>>> d[1].append({'b':2})
>>> d
{1: [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}]}
```

Comment: Thanks,
how can I access '2' in your example?

Comment: `d[1][1]['b']` meaning: 1) From the dictionary `d` get the value that corresponds to key `1`. 2) From the value (list) returned by step 1, get element `[1]` which is a dictionary. 3) From step two, lookup the value corresponding to the key `'b'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) and [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for this ([demo here](https://ideone.com/2M3g6w)):

```
with open('/path/to/file.txt', 'rU') as f:     # read the contents from the file
    lines = f.readlines()

import re
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)                          # dict with default value: []

lastKey = None
for line in lines:
    m = re.search('Column\d',line)             # search the current line for a key
    if m: lastKey = m.group()
    else:
        m = re.search('(?<=entry\d ).*',line)  # search the current line for a value
        if m: d[lastKey].append(m.group())     # append the value
```

**Output:**

```
[('Column1', ['val1', 'val2']), ('Column2', ['val3', 'val4'])]
```

---

**Note:** Of course, the above code assumes your file.txt was formatted as in your example. For your real file.txt data you might have to adjust the regex.